# Plotly create standalone colorbar

Tags: plotly, plotly-python, colorbar

I'm creating a Dash application with a few heatmaps through the px.imshow command. Now all of them have their own colorbar whick makes the figures much smaller than they could be. Therefore, I'd like to remove the colorbars from the individual figures (I know how to do this) and then just add a new figure with only a colorbar (provided with the min and max) All individual plots also have the same min and max.

So, how to make a plotly figure with only a colorbar in it?

Comment: Why not just removing the colorbar for all traces except for one ?

Comment: Because having a colorbar changes the dimensions of the actual plot, if only one of the figures has one then this plot will look differently form the others

Comment: Is it a requirement for you to have one figure per heatmap ? You could just create one figure (one plot) with multiple traces in it. Then it would just be a matter of setting the proper attributes.

Comment: That was my initial approach indeed but it would make much more sense layout wise to separate them so there can be some text and other things between them. I'm also using xarray's and leveraging its automatic labeling. This seems to be only supported with px.imshow and not with go.heatmap. In matplotlib this is easy to do (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16595138/standalone-colorbar) So i was hoping there's a plotly way as well.

Comment: I couldn't make my suggestion fit in a comment, so I provided an answer. Note that px.imshow uses go.heatmap (or go.Image) under the hood, so what is possible with imshow is necessarily possible with go.Heatmap.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating one figure per heatmap, you could just create one figure (one plot) with multiple traces in it. Then it would just be a matter of setting the proper attributes, that is: `zmin` and `zmax` (min,max of all heatmaps), and [`showscale`](https://plotly.com/python/reference/heatmap/#heatmap-showscale).

For example :

```py
z0 = np.arange(12**2).reshape((12, 12))
z1 = np.arange(15**2).reshape((15, 15))
z2 = np.arange(20**2).reshape((20, 20))

fig = make_subplots(rows=1, cols=3)

fig.add_heatmap(z=z0, row=1, col=1, zmin=0, zmax=20**2, showscale=True)
fig.add_heatmap(z=z1, row=1, col=2, showscale=False)
fig.add_heatmap(z=z2, row=1, col=3, showscale=False)

fig.show()
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to actually answer the question.  If I want to add other symbols between the plots (such as summation and other mathematical equations), there does not seem to be a way to do this with `make_subplots`.  And if I want to export the colorbar to an image for use in a larger graphic, and the colorbar needs to be separated from the plots, this does not help at all.

Answer (score -1):

As a workaround, you can overlay the heatmap with a white heatmap and narrow the width to the point where the colorbar takes up most of the width and is on top of the plot.

```py
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[0, 1]])
fig = go.Figure(
    data=[
        go.Heatmap(
            z=a,
            colorscale="Blues",
            showscale=True,
            zmin=a.min(),
            zmax=a.max(),
            colorbar=dict(x=0),
        ),
        go.Heatmap(
            z=np.zeros_like(a), # ensure there are enough points to cover the whole image
            colorscale="Picnic_r",  # any colorscale that has white at 0
            showscale=False,
            zmid=0,
        ),
    ],
)
fig.update_layout(
    width=75, # 75 seems to work empirically, you may have to adjust the width
    xaxis_showgrid=False,
    yaxis_showgrid=False,
    xaxis_zeroline=False,
    yaxis_zeroline=False,
    xaxis_visible=False,
    yaxis_visible=False,
    margin=dict(l=0, r=0, b=0, t=0), # zeroing the margins gives a tighter figure, and is also important to make the other numbers work out
)
fig.show("png")
```

(Code inpired by asking ChatGPT to translate the [answer for matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16595138/standalone-colorbar) to plotly.)

[image: rendering of the colorbar]