# Set two matplotlib imshow plots to have the same color map scale

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, colorbar, imshow

I am trying to plot to fields with the same scale. The upper image values are a 10 times higher than the one bellow, but they turn out to be the same color in the imshow. How can I set both to have the same scales in colours?

I added the code I am using bellow the image..

[image: Two imshow plots]

```
def show_field(field1,field2):
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(2, 1, 1)
    ax.imshow(field1,cmap=plt.cm.YlGn)
    ax.set_adjustable('box-forced')
    ax.autoscale(False)
    ax2 = fig.add_subplot(2, 1, 2)
    ax2.set_adjustable('box-forced')
    ax2.imshow(field2,cmap=plt.cm.YlGn)
    ax2.autoscale(False)
    plt.show()
```

Comment: You're looking for the `vmin` and `vmax` arguments.  (Side note, this is a duplicate question, though I can't find the canonical version at the moment...)

Comment: Yes I also haven't found this question, though I was sure that it was raised many times...

Comment: I'm fairly sure there's a more exact duplicate than the question I flagged this as a duplicate of... If you or anyone else comes across it, feel free to change it!

Comment: Blerg, well, I can't re-close it with the correct duplicate question, but here's a more exact duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3373256/set-colorbar-range-in-matplotlib/3376734#3376734

Comment: @JoeKington So what do you say, should I delete my question?

Comment: No, don't delete it. It's a good question, and there's nothing wrong with it being a duplicate.  It's actually better to have (closed) duplicates around, as people searching have a higher chance of finding their answer  (i.e. someone might be searching for something phrased very similar to your question title and find this).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

First you need to define the min and max of the color range you want to use. In this example it is the min and max of both arrays you are plotting. Then use these values to set the range of the imshow color code.

```
import numpy as np     
def show_field(field1,field2):

    combined_data = np.array([field1,field2])
    #Get the min and max of all your data
    _min, _max = np.amin(combined_data), np.amax(combined_data)

    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(2, 1, 1)
    #Add the vmin and vmax arguments to set the color scale
    ax.imshow(field1,cmap=plt.cm.YlGn, vmin = _min, vmax = _max)
    ax.set_adjustable('box-forced')
    ax.autoscale(False)
    ax2 = fig.add_subplot(2, 1, 2)
    ax2.set_adjustable('box-forced')
    #Add the vmin and vmax arguments to set the color scale
    ax2.imshow(field2,cmap=plt.cm.YlGn, vmin = _min, vmax = _max)
    ax2.autoscale(False)
    plt.show()
```

Comment: I didn't want to concatenate two very large matrices to get `combined_data`, so I just did `_min = min(field1.min(), field2.min())`.

Answer (score 0):

To compliment the accepted answer, here is a function that can make an arbitrary number of imshow plots that all share the same color map:

```
def show_fields(fields):
    combined_data = np.array(fields)
    #Get the min and max of all your data
    _min, _max = np.amin(combined_data), np.amax(combined_data)

    fig = plt.figure()
    for i in range(len(fields)):
        ax = fig.add_subplot(len(fields), 1, i+1)
        #Add the vmin and vmax arguments to set the color scale
        ax.imshow(fields[i],cmap=plt.cm.YlGn, vmin = _min, vmax = _max)
        ax.set_adjustable('box-forced')
        ax.autoscale(False)

    plt.show()
```

Usage:

```
show_fields([field1,field2,field3])
```