# matplotlib adjusting colorbar

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have a 2D data set with values between 0.5 and 2.
I want to show it with `imshow` and `seismic` color map but I need the value 1 to match the white color.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
data = np.random.random((100,100))*2
data[data<0.5]=0.5
plt.imshow(data,cmap='seismic')
plt.colorbar()
```

[image: example]

I did:

```
plt.imshow(data,cmap='seismic',vmin=0,vmax=2)
```

[image]

But I can't have the 0-0.5 values in my colorbar.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3373256/set-colorbar-range-in-matplotlib

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `ColorBar.set_clim()`:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
data = np.random.random((100,100))*2
data[data<0.5]=0.5
plt.imshow(data,cmap='seismic', vmin=0.5, vmax=2)
c = plt.colorbar()
c.set_clim(0, 2)
```

the output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! exactly what I needed