# set colorbar range with contourf

Tags: python, matplotlib, colorbar, contourf

This would appear to be a duplicate of this question:

[Set Colorbar Range in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3373256/set-colorbar-range-in-matplotlib)

Essentially I want to set the `colorbar` range to set limits, e.g. 0 to 2.  When I use `vmin` and `vmax`, the range of colors in `contourf` is correctly set, but colorbar only shows the clipped range, i.e. the solution in the link doesn't seem to work when using `contourf`.  Am I missing something obvious?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fld=np.random.rand(10,10)
img=plt.contourf(fld,20,cmap='coolwarm',vmin=0,vmax=2)
plt.colorbar(img)
```

Resulting in

[image]

How can I force the colorbar range to be 0 to 2 with `contourf`?

Comment: `np.random.rand` will generate random uniform numbers in the range 0-1. `np.random.rand(10, 10)*2' will change the range to 0-2.

Comment: thanks, yes, that is the idea of the reproducible example, I have data ranging 0-1 but want to plot with a larger range. My actually problem involves a large number of maps I want to compare using the same colorbar on each map, hence the question.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`contourf` indeed works a bit differently than other `ScalarMappable`s. If you specify the number of levels (20 in this case) it will take them between the minimum and maximum data (approximately). If you want to have `n` levels between two specific values `vmin` and `vmax` you would need to supply those to the contouring function

```
levels = np.linspace(vmin, vmax, n+1)
plt.contourf(fld,levels=levels,cmap='coolwarm')
```

Complete code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fld=np.random.rand(10,10)
levels = np.linspace(0,2,21)
img=plt.contourf(fld,levels=levels,cmap='coolwarm')
plt.colorbar(img)
plt.show()
```

[image]