# Setting colorbar bounds with only plt.colorbar()

Tags: matplotlib, fenics

So I'm plotting a solution to PDE with a program called fenics that has its own plot function. I can get the colorbar with plt.colorbar, how can I call it with fixed bounds such that the lower bound and upper bounds will always be the same regardless of data. What do I pass colorbar function so that there is a fixed lower and upper bound to the colorbar?

I have seen boundaries and ticks, but this isn't doing the trick

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set Colorbar Range in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3373256/set-colorbar-range-in-matplotlib)

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest fenics uses a plot function, when i set the result of plotting to a variable and add a colorbar to that object it appears on the plot when I plt.show

Comment: So `out = mysterious_function(); plt.colorbar(out); plt.show()` gives you the correct colorbar? Any chance you can give a hint on `mysterious_function` to possibly identify a canonical solution? If not, `out.set_clim(vmin,vmax)` might still work.

Comment: When I look at the type of the variable that is returned from the fenics plot and its  <class 'matplotlib.tri.tricontour.TriContourSet'>. It autofits the colorbar, I was interested in setting the colorbar to be for example on the interval -5 to 5 and color appropriately.

Comment: Ah, it's not possible to change the color range of a contour plot after it being created. The reason is that the contours would need to be recalculated from scratch in such case. Is there really no manual on the `mysterious_function`?

Comment: Not that I can find. RIP me lol :(

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
normi = matplotlib.colors.Normalize(vmin=0, vmax=1.0)
plt.figure(figsize=(10,8))
plt.title('Title')
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
c = plot(u)
c.set_norm(normi)
plt.colorbar(c)
```