# How to plot_surface with faster color changes?

Tags: python, matplotlib

i'm using `plot_surface` with one of existing color maps.

```
sub.plot_surface(X,Y,Z, cmap=cm.coolwarm)
```

but the color changes is not fast enough for me - i want to be able to spot smaller differences. i'd like change color e.g. every 0.5 unit. or draw some isolines. how can i do it?

Comment: You can use `vmin` and `vmax` to set the range of your color map.  [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3376734/10101556)

Comment: Try playing around with the `plt.set_clim(min,max)`  function.