# How can I use matplotlib to create a GIF whose frames share a commonly-scaled colorbar?

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors, gif, colorbar

I want to make a GIF animation of a wave propagation. My problem is the following: the colorbar should be constant for all the frames. How to make sure that the scale of the solution can be maintained from one frame to another, for the sake of readability?

Here is my code:

```py
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(7,7))
fig = dolfin.plot(u)

plt.title(r'$u(\mathbf{x}, t)$')
plt.xlabel(r'$x$ [m]')
plt.ylabel(r'$y$ [m]')
plt.colorbar(fig, fraction=0.058, pad=0.04)
plt.savefig('fig'+str(n)+'.png',bbox_inches='tight', dpi=150)
plt.close()
```

Comment: How do you want to create the frames - matplotlib, ...?

Comment: Yes with matplotlib.

And i solve my equation with dolphin (it's my 'u')

Comment: Start looking at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3373256/set-colorbar-range-in-matplotlib

Comment: `fig.colorbar()` then `fig.set_clim(a,b)`?  or `plt.clim(a,b)` https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.clim.html

Comment: I try that but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: It does something but the colorbar still changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my comments, you should just be able to add `plt.clim(vmin,vmax)`, or `fig.set_clim(vmin,vmax)`, as necessary.

Reference: https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.clim.html

Comment: It asks me:
"RuntimeError: You must first define an image, for example, with imshow."
How can I do that?

Comment: Have you tried `fig.set_clim()`?