# Matplotlib pcolormesh() atributes

Tags: python, matplotlib

If I have an existing `pcolormesh()` object is it possible to change the `vmin`, `vmax` values? In other words, are `vmin` and `vmax` attributes of the `pcolormesh` object?

Comment: Is `plt.clim(vmin, vmax)` what you're looking for? Or perhaps `.norm.autoscale([vmin, vmax])` See if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76412041

Comment: @cottontail this can be done through the object that `pcolormesh` returns. See my answer.

Comment: Yes, thank you! I'm not sure why this question/answer didn't show in my search?

Comment: @jared yes, that's what's done in the linked answer as well. Your answer is very nice too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To see an object's attributes you can use the `dir` function.

```py
p = plt.pcolormesh(...)
print(dir(p))  # lists all the attributes for this object
```

You'll see it has the `.set_clim()` attribute which you can use.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.close("all")

x = np.linspace(0, 1)
y = np.linspace(0, 1)
Z = x[:,None]**2 + y[None, :]**2

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
p = ax.pcolormesh(x, y, Z)
fig.colorbar(p, ax=ax)
fig.show()

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
p = ax.pcolormesh(x, y, Z)
p.set_clim(vmin=0.5, vmax=1.)
fig.colorbar(p, ax=ax)
fig.show()
```

First figure:

[image]

Second figure:

[image]