# How to convert data values into color information for matplotlib?

Tags: python, colors, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

I am using the class matplotlib.patches.Polygon to draw polygons on a map. In fact, the information about the coordinates of the corners of the polygons and a floating point data value for each "polygon" are given.
Now I'd like to convert these data values (ranging from 0 to 3e15) into color information to visualize it nicely. What is the best practice for doing that in Python?

A snippet of my code:

```
poly = Polygon( xy, facecolor=data, edgecolor='none')
plt.gca().add_patch(poly)
```

Comment: from help(matplotlib.pyplot.plot): `you can specify colors in many weird and
    wonderful ways, including full names ('green'), hex
    strings ('#008000'), RGB or RGBA tuples ((0,1,0,1)) or
    grayscale intensities as a string ('0.8')`

Comment: I think what you are looking for is a ColorMap. See the following post for information about using those provided by matplotlib. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8931268/using-colormaps-to-set-color-of-line-in-matplotlib If you want to make your own, the page below provides a nice example. http://code.activestate.com/recipes/52273-colormap-returns-an-rgb-tuple-on-a-0-to-255-scale-/

Answer (score 28, accepted):

In the RGB color system two bits of data are used for each color, red, green, and blue. That means that each color runs on a scale from 0 to 255. Black would be 00,00,00, while white would be 255,255,255. Matplotlib has lots of pre-defined colormaps for you to use. They are all normalized to 255, so they run from 0 to 1. So you need only normalize your data, then you can manually select colors from a color map as follows:

```
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

>>> Blues = plt.get_cmap('Blues')
>>> print Blues(0)
(0.9686274528503418, 0.9843137264251709, 1.0, 1.0)
>>> print Blues(0.5)
(0.41708574119736169, 0.68063054575639614, 0.83823145908467911, 1.0)
>>> print Blues(1.0)
(0.96555171293370867, 0.9823452528785257, 0.9990157632266774, 1.0)
```

Here are all of the [predefined colormaps.](http://wiki.scipy.org/Cookbook/Matplotlib/Show_colormaps) If you're interested in creating your own color maps, [here](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/custom_cmap.html) is a good example. Also [here](http://www.research.ibm.com/people/l/lloydt/color/color.HTM) is a paper from IBM on choosing colors carefully, something you should be considering if you're using color to visualize data.

Comment: I'm confused, 256 is 2**8, perhaps you mean 8 bits = 1 byte of data for each color?

Comment: The provided link appears to be broken

Answer (score 5):

To convert a value from that goes from 0 to + infinity to a value that goes from 0.0 to 1.0

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

price_change =  price_change ** 2 / (1 + price_change ** 2)
Blues = plt.get_cmap('Blues')
print Blues(price_change)
```

A full list of colormaps is here: http://matplotlib.org/users/colormaps.html