# Discrete colorbar in matplotlib

Tags: python, colorbar

I have found on the internet a way to use a colobar with only N colors. Here is the example

```
cmap = cm.jet
cmaplist = [cmap(i) for i in range(cmap.N)]
cmap = cmap.from_list('Custom cmap', cmaplist, cmap.N)
bounds = linspace(0,len(my_values),len(my_values)+1)
```

where `my_values` is

```
my_values=array([0.,1.,2.,3.,4.,5.,6.])
```

Let's assume we have two arrays, `x` and `y`, that represent the position of random points. A third array, `c`, is associated to each point and can only take values from `my_values`.

The following code will plot a scatter plot and the colorbar is divided into 7 discrete levels.

```
scatter(x,y,c=c);colorbar(boundaris=bounds)
```

My question is, how can I retrieve the color (in rgb, hex or whatever) of each of the 7 levels?

Comment: Your example looks similar to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14777066/matplotlib-discrete-colorbar). You may look into [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8931268/using-colormaps-to-set-color-of-line-in-matplotlib) which discusses using [ScalarMappable](http://matplotlib.org/api/cm_api.html) from `matplotlib.cm`.

Comment: thanks, it actually did the trick