# How to pick unique colors of histogram bars in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

I am trying to plot a several histogram on the same plot but I figured out that some colors are assigned to different series, which bother me a little. Is there a way of forcing color bars to be unique ?

That works for small data set, but when I use a lot of data, I see this problem coming back

here is an example, the blue color is assigned twice to two different data samples

[image]

All the examples and the solutions to attribute colors to histograms in matplotlib (at least those I found) are suggesting to normalize x axis between 0 and 1 like [this example](http://matplotlib.org/1.2.1/examples/pylab_examples/hist_colormapped.html) , but this is not what I want to have because it is very important to have the real values in my case.

Is there another solution ?

Thanks

**EDIT**

One solution I came with is to convert a cmap palette to a numpy array and use pyplot hist color by calling this palette

```
N = len(list_of_samples)
sample_colors = cm.get_cmap('RdYlBu', N)
palette = sample_colors(np.arange(N))
```

But this works only for hist for plot function I got this error message

```
ValueError: to_rgba: Invalid rgba arg "[[ 0.64705884  0.          0.14901961  1.        ]
 [ 0.89187675  0.2907563   0.20000001  1.        ]
 [ 0.98711484  0.64593837  0.36358543  1.        ]
 [ 0.99719888  0.91316527  0.61736696  1.        ]
 [ 0.91316529  0.96638656  0.90868344  1.        ]
 [ 0.63977591  0.82633053  0.90028011  1.        ]
 [ 0.34957983  0.55294117  0.75462185  1.        ]
 [ 0.19215687  0.21176471  0.58431375  1.        ]]"
only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

Comment: You need it for the ```plot``` function as well? Can you give some example code demonstrating how you want to plot and what should be colored differently? (Maybe [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8931396/3419103) is already what you need.)

Comment: Hmm this might do what I am looking for indeed, thanks  a lot @Falko

Comment: Check the following answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61794768/7136493 .

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A solution for histograms is as follows:

```
import pylab as pl

N, bins, patches = pl.hist(pl.rand(1000), 20)

jet = pl.get_cmap('jet', len(patches))

for i in range(len(patches)):
    patches[i].set_facecolor(jet(i))
```

Result:

[image]

I hope that's what you are looking for.

Comment: as I said in my question I am not looking to alter (normalize) the x axis values from 0 to one unfortunately

Comment: You don't have to. Assigning colors works independently of your x and y values.