# bar plot with different colors in python

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, matplotlib

I have data like this :

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
index={'A','B','C','D','E'}
d={'typ':[1,2,2,2,1],'value':[10,25,15,17,13]}
df=pd.DataFrame(d,index=index)
```

I want to plot the dataframe in horizontal bars with different colors reffering to the column `'typ'`

Comment: Perhaps the accepted answer to another [matplotlib question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25396786/how-to-pick-unique-colors-of-histogram-bars-in-matplotlib) may help you: it cycles through the individual bars (patches) and assigns a color to each patch individually. You'll need to adopt it for a barchart plot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `color` parameter of matplotlib's [`barh`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.barh) function:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
index={'A','B','C','D','E'}
d={'typ':[1,2,2,2,1],'value':[10,25,15,17,13]}
df=pd.DataFrame(d,index=index)

# define the colors for each type
colors = {1:'blue', 2:'red'}

# plot the bars
plt.bar(range(len(df)), df['value'], align='center',
        color=[colors[t] for t in df['typ']])
```

[image: The resulting figure]