# seaborn histogram to have different color bins

Tags: python, plot, seaborn

A simple histogram by seaborn. I want to highlight the top 3 bins with a different color. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43831029/matplotlib-seaborn-histogram-using-different-colors-for-grouped-bins/47391815) shows a matplotlib way, but not a seaborn way.

Is there any ways to show different colored bins in seaborn?

Thank you.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.random.normal(loc = 6, size=100)
ax = sns.distplot(data, bins = 20)
plt.xlim(0, 10)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there are no other plots on the same ax, you could loop through all its patches, find the 3 highest and color them:

```py
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.random.normal(loc = 6, size=500)
ax = sns.distplot(data, bins = 20)

heights = [p.get_height() for p in ax.patches]
third_highest = sorted(heights)[-3]
for p in ax.patches:
    if  p.get_height() >= third_highest:
        p.set_color('crimson')

plt.xlim(0, 10)
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

Comment: Marvelous. Thank you for the help and knowledge sharing!

Answer (score 1):

Stumbled across this question today too and JohanC's answer worked very well!

One little addition I would add is that if you like your bars to have borders you can swap the `p.set_color` with `p.set_facecolor`, that way if your original plot has bars with borders it will keep the borders intact.