# How can I draw a points with a normalized color in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I've got the following code:

```
x = range(1, 100) # pixel x coordinates
y = range(21, 120) # pixel y coordinates
z = [-2, 5, 1, ..., 1] # should be mapped to colors

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm
from matplotlib.colors import Normalize

cmap = cm.autumn
norm = Normalize(vmin=min(z), vmax=max(z))
colormap = cmap(norm(5))
plt.plot(x, y, cm=colormap)
```

And now I want to plot these points `[x, y]` such that:

1. Each point should be a pixel (since `len(x)` may be about `35'000`), not just a marker (I'm afraid they'll overlap otherways).
2. Using [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8931268/using-colormaps-to-set-color-of-line-in-matplotlib), I'd like to take a colormap and map `min(z)` to let's say white color and `max(z)` to a black color (and display a legend).

How can I do it using matplotlib?

Comment: What code have you tried so far? Please include that in your question.

Comment: @HS-nebula added my code.

Comment: https://matplotlib.org/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/multicolored_line.html#sphx-glr-gallery-lines-bars-and-markers-multicolored-line-py

Comment: Do x, y and z have the same length? Are all pixels in a quadratic space "occupied" or just some?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are talking about pixels instead of markers, and I don't know whether you got data for all pixel coordinates or just for some, I'm gonna show you something for both. I'll include the `numpy` package, because it makes everything with arrays easier.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm
from matplotlib.colors import Normalize

x = range(1, 100) # pixel x coordinates
y = range(21, 120) # pixel y coordinates
```

Assuming you have z-data for all coordinates spanned by `[x, y]`:

```
In [1]: z = np.random.rand(len(x), len(y)) # should be mapped to colors
plt.imshow(z)
plt.colorbar()
Out [1]:
```

[image]

Assuming every `z` value maps to a `[x, y]` coordinate pair, but not all coordinates are covered:

```
In [2]:
z = np.random.rand(len(x))

arr = np.zeros([max(x) + 1, max(y) + 1])
arr[x, y] = z

plt.imshow(arr)
plt.colorbar()

Out [2]:
```

[image]