# matplotlib: AttributeError: 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'add_axes'

Tags: python, matplotlib, axes

Not sure exactly sure how to fix the following attribute error:

```
AttributeError: 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'add_axes'
```

The offending problem seems to be linked to the way I have set up my plot:

```
gridspec_layout = gridspec.GridSpec(3,3)
pyplot_2 = fig.add_subplot(gridspec_layout[2])

ax = WCSAxes(fig, [0.1, 0.1, 0.8, 0.8], wcs=wcs)
pyplot_2.add_axes(ax)
```

Does anybody know how to solve this? Many thanks.

Answer (score 6):

You now need to use set_prop_cycle i.e. `ax.set_prop_cycle(color=['red', 'green', 'blue'])`

Axes.set_color_cycle(clist) was depreciated since, version 1.5.

https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_prop_cycle.html

Answer (score 5):

There's not much details to go on in your question but I'll wager a guess.
The error is pretty self-explanatory. You can't `add_axes` to `pyplot_2` because `pyplot_2` is a `matplotlib.axes.AxesSubplot` object and they don't have an `add_axes` method defined.

Only `matplotlib.figure.Figure` objects have `add_axes` method defined on them.

From what I got from a short browse through the WCSAxes official documentation their recommended approach would be:

```
wcs = astropy.wcs.WCS(....)
fig = matplotlib.pyplot.figure()
pyplot_2 = fig.add_subplot(gridspec_layout[2], projection=wcs)
```

Answer (score 1):

I did a `conda update pandas` and the error went away. Nothing else I could find worked.

Mine was a slightly different flavor of this error (not 'add_axes'). It happened when I was trying to use pandas.DataFrame.plot within matplotlib subplots.

I was on pandas 0.25.3 before and after, and a number of packages were upgraded/downgraded.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this same error several days ago on both a Macbook and a Lenovo laptop. I used Anaconda for my python installation on both computers.

This is a problem with the Matplotlib package management. So the solution for me was to remove Matplotlib and reinstall it. Then the error is gone.

Answer (score -4):

Just downgrading matplotlib to an old version would help. I downgraded it to 1.4.0 and it fixed the problem.

Comment: Downgrading a package should never be a solution.

Comment: @yeliabsalohcin you could fork it, if you so desire