# How can I stop Matplotlib from repeating colors?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have this code:

```
plist = ['p5', 'p14', 'p23', 'p32', 'p41', 'p50', 'p59', 'p68', 'p77', 'p85', 'p95']


for pltcount in range(len(plist)):
    plt.plot(data1[pltcount], np.exp(data2)[pltcount], marker='o', label=str(plist[pltcount]))
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

This is using the `plt.style.use('fivethirtyeight')`   to make the plots nicer. I have found examples where I manually assign the colors. What if I want it to be automatic and from some well-known palettes?

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

How about the colors of the rainbow? The key here is to use `ax.set_prop_cycle` to assign colors to each line.

```
NUM_COLORS = len(plist)

cm = plt.get_cmap('gist_rainbow')
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.set_prop_cycle('color', [cm(1.*i/NUM_COLORS) for i in range(NUM_COLORS)])
# Or,
# ax.set_prop_cycle(color=[cm(1.*i/NUM_COLORS) for i in range(NUM_COLORS)])
for i, p in enumerate(plist):
    ax.plot(data1[i], np.exp(data2)[i], marker='o', label=str(p))

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[Borrowed from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8389636/creating-over-20-unique-legend-colors-using-matplotlib). Other options possible.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I think NUM_COLORS should be `len(plist)`. Works perfectly!

Comment: I do get this warning: ` The set_color_cycle function was deprecated in version 1.5. Use `.set_prop_cycle`` instead.

Comment: For now, I get this error if I replace it with set_prop_cycle: `TypeError: If only one positional argument given, it must  be a Cycler instance.1` checking syntax..

Comment: @maximusdooku I've done a little research and edited my answer. How does that work?

Comment: Awesome! Perfect now.