# How can I fix legend color issue in Bar graph in Python?

Tags: python, dataframe, plot, colors

I have a problem about defining many color in legend part of bar graph.

After I've done some essential process, I draw a figure by using the code shown below.

```
ax = df.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True,figsize=(13,10))
plt.title('Title List', fontsize=20) 
leg = ax.legend(loc='center right', bbox_to_anchor=(1.3, 0.5), ncol=1)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.savefig('images/image1.png', bbox_inches = "tight")  
plt.show()
```

When I run the code, some colors are the same.

How can I define unique colors in legend part?

Here is the screenshot
[image]

Comment: please attach screenshots of your output

Comment: @Divyessh Maheshwari  I attached the color of legend screenshot.

Comment: alll the mains colors are occupied.

Comment: there are 10 main colors

Comment: @Divyessh Maheshwari How can I define them as an unique

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8389636/creating-over-20-unique-legend-colors-using-matplotlib refer to this

Comment: @Divyessh Maheshwari I want to add color in the legend not plot.

Comment: does your plot have differrent colors

Comment: your plot will also need to have different colors I guess

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218809/discussion-between-divyessh-maheshwari-and-tony-brand).

Comment: Hello sorry but I am unable to get an answer for it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My answer:

After I defining `colormap` as rainbow, All defined colors in legend parts became unique.

Change to code

```
ax = df.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True,figsize=(13,10))
```

to

```
ax = df.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True,figsize=(13,10), colormap='rainbow')
```